# Resizing Images for full-screen applications?

Tags: java, swing, fullscreen, bufferedimage

I've got a full-screen JFrame and I'd like to create an background for it by filling a JLabel with an image and matching it's size to the dimension of the screen.

Whilst I can create a JLabel that matches the screen's size I can't seem to resize my image to fit. In essence, I want to end up with a full-screen JFrame that is completely filled with an image (regardless of the image's or the screen's dimensions).

Current code is below, thanks!

```
public void addBackground(ImageIcon imgIcon) {
  Image img = imgIcon.getImage();
  BufferedImage buffImg = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
  BufferedImage resizeBuffImg = resize(buffImg, screenSize.width, screenSize.height); 
  Image finalImg = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(resizeBuffImg.getSource());
  ImageIcon back = new ImageIcon(finalImg);

  System.out.println("IMAGE WIDTH: " + back.getIconWidth());
  System.out.println("IMAGE HEIGHT: " + back.getIconHeight());

  JLabel backgroundLabel = new JLabel(back);
  getContentPane().add(backgroundLabel);      
}

public BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage image, int width, int height) {
  int type = image.getType() == 0? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : image.getType();
  BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, type);
  Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
  g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);

  g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
  RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);

  g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
  RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

  g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
  RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

  g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
  g.dispose();
  return resizedImage;
}
```

EDIT - Got it! Using Image's getScaledInstance() works. It's not perfect, but I'm intending to scale down large images rather than expand smaller ones.

Comment: One way to solve this: listen for re-size events using a ComponentListener.

Comment: Another way is to override paintComponent and check if image size and component size match.